# spring-cloud-stream rabbit binder un-partitioned destination

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I'm using spring-cloud-stream : 2.1.1.RELEASE  with Rabbit binder.

The queue names generated for my binding always have a -0 extension like :

test-data-direct.group01-0

test-data-direct is the exchange name
and group01 is the group name.

How can I avoid the -0 extension ?

spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.output.producer.partitioned : false

didn't help

Comment: Show your yaml/properties for both sides. Producers don't bind queues unless requiredgroups is set.

Comment: @GaryRussell, I just have the producer side config. I realized that there was a leftover 
spring.cloud.stream.default.producer.partitionkeyexpression

setting in my yml.

Removing it caused the queues to be created without -0 extension.

Answer (score 0):

The queues creation is triggered/influenced by the *consumer* properties. Meanwhile your `...partitioned : false` is set on *producer*. You probably have something like

```
input:
    consumer:
        instanceCount: 3
        instanceIndex: 0
        partitioned: true
```

. . . which would explain your queue names.